# Dual table default value?

Tags: oracle

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73751/what-is-the-dual-table-in-oracle) link clear some of the queries about dual table.

But now I am having following doubt is the execution of two queries on dual table:

Query 1

```
Select * from dual;
```

output:

```
D
-
X
```

Query2

```
Select NUll from dual;
```

output:

```
D
-
```

Does Dual contain default value as NULL? If yes why blank is not displayed, as in case of second query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a display issue.

```
SQL> select NULL from DUAL;

N
-


SQL>
```

Using `NVL` to display `NULL` instead of a blank:

```
SQL> select NVL((select NULL from DUAL), 'NULL') from DUAL;

NVL(
----
NULL

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

Phil has an interesting test case. But the dual table has one column and one row with the value x. When you select NULL from dual you are selecting a literal from a table. The literal is not actually in the table. That you can select sysdate from dual does not mean 
that sysdate is in the dual table either.

```
SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
---------------
23-MAY-14
```